# How to dynamically link to DLL (Dynamic-link library) when using MinGW?

Tags: mingw, dynamic-linking

I have put `sqlite3.dll` at my compilation folder, but when I use `-l sqlite3` option on MinGW compiler, It results: `ld.exe: cannot find -lsqlite3`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using SQLite with C on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540355/using-sqlite-with-c-on-windows)

Comment: What's the point of using a system library that is not part of the system?

Comment: Thanks CL.. I have edited that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing `-L.` option at my command. It works:

```
gcc -o nonamed.exe main.c -L. -lsqlite3
```

Alternatively you can do:

```
gcc -o nonamed.exe main.c sqlite3.dll
```